# cmake CheckCSourceCompiles passes preprocessor-definitions to armlink

Tags: c++, cmake, armcc

I am trying to check thread_local(which is provided as __thread or __declspec(thread) ) feature in `armcc`.

```
CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES("int main(){ static __thread int num; return 0;}" GCC_THREAD_LOCAL_AVAILABLE)
```

With my version of armcc, I am able to compile the source code in above cmake command without any error.

But cmake fails this test with following log:

```
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_293ce.dir/src.o
/opt/ARM/DS-5//bin/armcc   -DGCC_THREAD_LOCAL_AVAILABLE  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_293ce.dir/src.o   -c /devdisk/users/gjha/code/aepe15_dryos_2nd/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
"/devdisk/users/gjha/code/aepe15_dryos_2nd/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c", line 1: Warning:  #177-D: variable "num" was declared but never referenced
  int main(){ static __thread int num; return 0;}
                                  ^
/devdisk/users/gjha/code/aepe15_dryos_2nd/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c: 1 warning, 0 errors
Linking C executable cmTC_293ce.elf
/opt/cmake394/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_293ce.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/ARM/DS-5/bin/armlink  -DGCC_THREAD_LOCAL_AVAILABLE    CMakeFiles/cmTC_293ce.dir/src.o  -o cmTC_293ce.elf
Warning: L3910W: Old syntax, please use '-d'.
Fatal error: L3900U: Unrecognized option '-GCC_THREAD_LOCAL_AVAILABLE'.
Finished: 0 information, 1 warning, 0 error and 1 fatal error messages.
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_293ce.elf] Error 1
```

Problem here is, cmake spills macro definition `-DGCC_THREAD_LOCAL_AVAILABLE` into linker command and `armlink` fails.

Please guide me how to avoid this macro definition spilling.

```
ARMCC version: 5.04
cmake version: 3.9.4
```

For GCC this problem does not occur and `gnu-ld` simply ignores the macro definition in the command line.

Comment: The second argument for `CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES` is just a variable name. So, what is origin of `-DGCC_THREAD_LOCAL_AVAILABLE` compile option? Do you set `CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS` variable or what?

Comment: No cmake invents this macro definition from the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source for the Module `CMake/Modules/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.cmake` is as following:

```
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License.  See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.

#[=======================================================================[.rst:
CheckCXXSourceCompiles
----------------------

Check if given C++ source compiles and links into an executable.

.. command:: check_cxx_source_compiles

  ::

    check_cxx_source_compiles(code resultVar [FAIL_REGEX regex1 [regex2...]])

  Check that the source supplied in ``code`` can be compiled as a C++ source
  file and linked as an executable (so it must contain at least a ``main()``
  function). The result will be stored in the internal cache variable specified
  by ``resultVar``, with a boolean true value for success and boolean false for
  failure. If ``FAIL_REGEX`` is provided, then failure is determined by
  checking if anything in the output matches any of the specified regular
  expressions.

  The underlying check is performed by the :command:`try_compile` command. The
  compile and link commands can be influenced by setting any of the following
  variables prior to calling ``check_cxx_source_compiles()``:

  ``CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS``
    Additional flags to pass to the compiler. Note that the contents of
    :variable:`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS <CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS>` and its associated
    configuration-specific variable are automatically added to the compiler
    command before the contents of ``CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS``.

  ``CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS``
    A :ref:`;-list <CMake Language Lists>` of compiler definitions of the form
    ``-DFOO`` or ``-DFOO=bar``. A definition for the name specified by
    ``resultVar`` will also be added automatically.

  ``CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES``
    A :ref:`;-list <CMake Language Lists>` of header search paths to pass to
    the compiler. These will be the only header search paths used by
    ``try_compile()``, i.e. the contents of the :prop_dir:`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`
    directory property will be ignored.

  ``CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES``
    A :ref:`;-list <CMake Language Lists>` of libraries to add to the link
    command. These can be the name of system libraries or they can be
    :ref:`Imported Targets <Imported Targets>` (see :command:`try_compile` for
    further details).

  ``CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET``
    If this variable evaluates to a boolean true value, all status messages
    associated with the check will be suppressed.

  The check is only performed once, with the result cached in the variable
  named by ``resultVar``. Every subsequent CMake run will re-use this cached
  value rather than performing the check again, even if the ``code`` changes.
  In order to force the check to be re-evaluated, the variable named by
  ``resultVar`` must be manually removed from the cache.

#]=======================================================================]

include_guard(GLOBAL)

macro(CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES SOURCE VAR)
  if(NOT DEFINED "${VAR}")
    set(_FAIL_REGEX)
    set(_key)
    foreach(arg ${ARGN})
      if("${arg}" MATCHES "^(FAIL_REGEX)$")
        set(_key "${arg}")
      elseif(_key)
        list(APPEND _${_key} "${arg}")
      else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown argument:\n  ${arg}\n")
      endif()
    endforeach()

    set(MACRO_CHECK_FUNCTION_DEFINITIONS
      "-D${VAR} ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS}")
    if(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES)
      set(CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_LIBRARIES
        LINK_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES})
    else()
      set(CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_LIBRARIES)
    endif()
    if(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES)
      set(CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_INCLUDES
        "-DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES:STRING=${CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES}")
    else()
      set(CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_INCLUDES)
    endif()
    file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeTmp/src.cxx"
      "${SOURCE}\n")

    if(NOT CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
      message(STATUS "Performing Test ${VAR}")
    endif()
    try_compile(${VAR}
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
      ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
      COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS}
      ${CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_LIBRARIES}
      CMAKE_FLAGS -DCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS:STRING=${MACRO_CHECK_FUNCTION_DEFINITIONS}
      "${CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_INCLUDES}"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT)

    foreach(_regex ${_FAIL_REGEX})
      if("${OUTPUT}" MATCHES "${_regex}")
        set(${VAR} 0)
      endif()
    endforeach()

    if(${VAR})
      set(${VAR} 1 CACHE INTERNAL "Test ${VAR}")
      if(NOT CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
        message(STATUS "Performing Test ${VAR} - Success")
      endif()
      file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeOutput.log
        "Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test ${VAR} succeeded with the following output:\n"
        "${OUTPUT}\n"
        "Source file was:\n${SOURCE}\n")
    else()
      if(NOT CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
        message(STATUS "Performing Test ${VAR} - Failed")
      endif()
      set(${VAR} "" CACHE INTERNAL "Test ${VAR}")
      file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeError.log
        "Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test ${VAR} failed with the following output:\n"
        "${OUTPUT}\n"
        "Source file was:\n${SOURCE}\n")
    endif()
  endif()
endmacro()
```

If I update the `try_compile` command in the module as following, I am able to check C++ features with `armcc` without any error.

```
try_compile(${VAR}
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS}
  ${CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_LIBRARIES}
  "${CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES_ADD_INCLUDES}"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT)
```